# Typescript global variables becoming undefined after function call

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my code, I have two global variables defined as

```
constructor() {
        this.map = new Map();
        this.player = new Player([], "");
    }
```

I can access these variables through my program normally, however when I call one of my functions `this.handleInput(Command.GO, "north");` where Command.GO translates to "GO" and "north" is a direction to go to, all of my global variables become undefined. In the handleInput method,

```
private handleInput(cmd:Command, arg:string):boolean {
      console.log("Handling", cmd, "with argument '"+arg+"'");
      if (cmd === "GO") {
            console.log(`You go ${arg}`);
                this.player.setCurrentLocation(this.map.getNextLocation(arg).getName());
                this.updateGame(this.map.getNextLocation(arg));
            }      
        }
```

I immediately get errors that this.player and this.map are undefined, however they were not undefined before I called the method! Is there something about global variables in TS/JS that I'm not grasping?

Comment: How is `handleInput` being called

Comment: How exactly do you call `handleInput`? Also try `console.log(this)` inside the method to see what's going wrong…

Answer (score 3):

Your `this` is most likely referring to another object depending on how `handleInput` is being called. In your `contructor()`, either `bind` `handleInput` to `this` or change your `handleInput` to use arrow function:

```
constructor() {
  this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
}
```

Or:

```
handleInput = (cmd:Command, arg:string):boolean => {}
```